# Water pressure in second floor very low

Tags: water-pressure

It has been couple of weeks now that the water pressure in the second floor - two sinks, toilet tank and shower is very low/dripping, but the first floor kitchen and bathroom water pressure is fine. If it was only a shower head, it might have been related to scaling etc, but wondering why overall floor has this issue.
Water leak was another possibility, but in three weeks, I would have imagined leak stains to start appearing on my ceiling.
any ideas before a plumber opens up everything!

Comment: It's not a leak. that would affect both floors and, um, how do I say this nicely, to drastically reduce water pressure, it would be "noticeable". Not knowing more about your plumbing, I can only guess, but it's almost certainly a blockage someplace or low water pressure that makes the first floor appear to be operating properly but not enough pressure for the 2nd floor....unlikely though.  Do you know the pressure on your first floor?

Comment: If you have galvanized steel plumbing then it could have rusted on the inside. If you're on public water and some large chunk of foreign object such as rust came from the source and into your house then that could be causing a blockage somewhere.